# Website looks great in every browser, except in Safari

Tags: css, html, safari

My website looks good in every browser (Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer) except Safari..

It's supposed to look like this:

[image: Correct]

But in Safari it looks like this:

[image: Correct]

Website url: http://themavesite.com/testlogin/

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: In safari 8.0 ( mac ) looks fine.

Comment: welcome to the world of website rendering differences per browser ;)

Comment: @Salmen that's odd.. On my Safari 5.1.7 (windows) it looks like the screenshot above :/

Comment: one way to get around browser limitations is to use a [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)...

Comment: maybe you have to add some vendor prefix in css file.

Comment: Try: input {line-height:1}

Answer (score 0):

The bugs apparently only appear in the Windows version of Safari.
Since no windows users would ever use Safari as default browser, I'm marking this thread as solved.